# Gegenwort zu "nur"

Tags: word-choice, single-word-request

**Nur** drückt aus, dass etwas wenig ist. Welche Möglichkeiten haben wir, um auszudrücken, dass etwas viel ist?

Was mir spontan einfällt:

> Er ist *ganze* 5 Kilometer gelaufen.

Dieser Weg versagt aber z. B. im folgenden Fall:

> Sie hatte **nur** bis zu ihrem 3. Lebensjahr Angst vor Geistern. *(Sinn dieses Satzes sei dahingestellt.)*
>
> Sie hatte ..... bis zu ihrem 30. Lebensjahr Angst vor Geistern. *(Wir wollen hervorheben, dass es vergleichsweise lange war, z. B. bezogen darauf, was sonst der Fall ist.)*

oder im Folgenden:

> Er besitzt ... drei Autos.

Wie kann man hier den Gegensatz zu *nur* ausdrücken?

Comment: Es drückt nicht wirklich das Gegenteil von "nur" aus, aber **sage und schreibe** wird häufig für etwas überraschend großes verwendet. Funktioniert in jedem deiner Beispiele. – Suchst du ein Singlewort, ist "sogar" das Wort, das am ehesten passt. Bedenke nur, es gibt kein Wort, dass immer in jedem Beispiel als Antonym verwendet werden kann.

Comment: Kein Wort. Einfach Betonung auf die Zahl... passt fast immer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Zeitlich:

> *noch* bis zum 30. Lebensjahr

Numerisch:

> *nicht weniger als* drei Autos

(Ja, Letzteres ist viel uneleganter als das entgegengesetzte "nur". So ist Sprache nun einmal: immer gerade asymmetrisch genug, um den Lerner in den Wahnsinn zu treiben.)

(Wenn man den Gegensatz zu einem Normalmenschen herstellt, der nur ein Auto besitzt, geht auch:

> *sogar* drei Autos

Das funktioniert aber leider nicht als isolierte Aussage.)

Comment: Und örtlich? `Sie rannte nur bis zum ersten Pfosten.` <--> ???

Comment: Das ist noch uneleganter: "Sie rannte den ganzen Parcours bis zum letzten Pfosten." (Ja, man muß Extra-Material in den Satz einbringen!!) Kolloquial auch: "Sie rannte ganz bis zum letzten Pfosten."

Comment: @BarthZalewski bis zum allerletzten Pfosten, sogar bis zum letzten Pfosten

Answer (score 2):

Jetzt, wo ich nochmals hier drüber lese, fällt mir auf, dass in manchem Kontext *gar* ein wenig besser ist als *sogar*:

> Er hatte gar bis zu seinem 30. Lebenjahr...

In anderen Beispielen funktioniert es theoretisch auch, klingt aber nicht ganz wirklich so gut:

> Er rannte gar bis zum letzten Pfosten.
>   Er hat gar drei Autos.

In den Fällen bleibe ich dabei, dass die Verwendung von *sage und schreibe* eine Überlegung wert ist.

Comment: +1, allerdings klingt *gar* etwas altmodisch in meinen Ohren.

Comment: "Besser" als sogar... nach welchen Kriterien?